# Issue producing a valid WIF key with Python 3.6 (Pythonista - iPadOS)

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, bitcoin

I am having some issues with some code. I have set about a project for creating Bitcoin wallets in an attempt to turn a hobby into a learning experience, whereby I can understand both Python and the Bitcoin protocol in more detail. I have posted here rather than in the Bitcoin site as the question is related to Python programming.

Below I have some code which I have created to turn a private key into a WIF key. I have written this out for clarity rather than the most optimal method of coding, so that I can see all the steps clearly and work on issues. This code was previously a series lines which I have now progressed into a class with functions.

I am following the example from this page: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format

Here is my current code:

```
import hashlib
import codecs


class wif():
    
    def private_to_wif(private_key):
        
        extended_key = wif.create_extended(private_key)
        address = wif.create_wif_address(extended_key)
        
        return address
        
    def create_extended(private_key):
        
        private_key1 = bytes.fromhex(private_key)
        private_key2 = codecs.encode(private_key1, 'hex')
        mainnet = b'80'
        #testnet = b'ef'
        #compressed = b'01'
        extended_key = mainnet + private_key2
        
        return extended_key
        
    def create_wif_address(extended_key):
        
        first_hash = hashlib.sha256(extended_key)
        first_digest = first_hash.digest()
        second_hash = hashlib.sha256(first_digest)
        second_digest = second_hash.digest()
        second_digest_hex = codecs.encode(second_digest, 'hex')
        checksum = second_digest_hex[:8]
        extended_key_chksm = (extended_key + checksum).decode('utf-8')
        wif_address = base58(extended_key_chksm)
        
        return wif_address
        
def base58(extended_key_chksm):
        
        alphabet = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        b58_string = ''
        leading_zeros = len(extended_key_chksm) - len(extended_key_chksm.lstrip('0'))
        address_int = int(extended_key_chksm, 16)
        while address_int > 0:
            digit = address_int % 58
            digit_char = alphabet[digit]
            b58_string = digit_char + b58_string
            address_int //= 58
        ones = leading_zeros // 2
        for one in range(ones):
            b58_string = '1' + b58_string
        
        return b58_string
```

I then use a few lines of code to get this working, using the example private key from the above guide, as follows:

```
key = ‘0C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D‘
address = wif.private_to_wif(key)
Print(address)
```

I should be getting the output: 5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ

Instead I’m getting:
`5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbWs6eYX`

It’s only the last 6 characters that differ!

Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Connor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the solution by adding a missing encoding step.

I am posting for all those who run into a similar issue and can see the steps that brought resolution.

```
def create_wif_address(extended_key):
    
    extended_key_dec = codecs.decode(extended_key, 'hex')
    first_hash = hashlib.sha256(extended_key_dec)
    first_digest = first_hash.digest()
    second_hash = hashlib.sha256(first_digest)
    second_digest = second_hash.digest()
    second_digest_hex = codecs.encode(second_digest, 'hex')
    checksum = second_digest_hex[:8]
    extended_key_chksm = (extended_key + checksum).decode('utf-8')
    wif_address = base58(extended_key_chksm)
    
    return wif_address
```

So above I added in a step to the function, at the beginning, to decode the passed in variable from a hexadecimal byte string to raw bytes, which is what the hashing algorithms require it seems, and this produced the result I was hoping to achieve.

Connor